# Can I explicitly ignore conditional mapping on an Entity Framework table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

so I am using Entity Framework with a Sqlite database to track a series of notes.
There is a business requirement that states that all edits and deletes are non-destructive. i.e. they are flagged as deleted and just hang out in the database in case they need to be resurrected for auditing purposes.

I found an extremely helpful [blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94784/Using-Conditional-Mapping-in-Entity-Framework) which accomplishes this. I am wondering if I can go a step further and give admins the ability to view these deleted records in a simple manner, or even mark them as "un-deleted" again.

Example of the **Note** entity

- ID (int)
- Note (string)
- CreatedBy (string)
- EditedBy (string)
- Last Modified (DateTime)
- DateDeleted (DateTime)

I have conditional mapping that says "if DateDeleted != null, then include this record in a query"

Before I get too far with conditional mapping, I'm wondering whether or not it's possible to explicitly override the conditional mapping and say **I don't care whether a record is marked as deleted or not... just get me all the records anyway**

**Idea #1**

Screw conditional formatting. Just make a property that uses LINQ to get the objects I want. I'm leaning toward this idea but would still like answers to the question for the sake of learning.

Comment: I'd go with "Idea #1".  The conditional mapping just seems to make things more complicated without any benefit.